# Optimizing a multiplicator in a nested C++ loop

Tags: c++, optimization, loops, nested

Hello I have the following snippet

```
  for(int k = 0; k< 1000; ++k)
    {

        double acc = 1.0;

        if(...)
        {
            short amSeq = 100;

            for (short c = 0; c <= 21; ++c)
            {
                for (short kk = (Range.uSequences[k][c]), s = SeqComp[c]; kk != 0; --kk, --s, --amSeq)
                {
                    acc *= static_cast<double>(s) / amSeq;
                }
            }
        }
        else
            acc = 0;

    }
```

I was wondering if there is any way to optimize the line `acc *= static_cast<double>(s) / amSeq;` removing the static_cast speeds up things by a factor of 200 but will obviously yield incorrect results. Thanks

Comment: What type is s? or SeqComp for that matter?  What platform are you talking about?  But you may find changing it to "acc *= static_cast<float>(s) / amSeq;" will make a massive difference .. especially if you make acc a float too ...

Comment: You wouldn't need a cast if `SeqComp` were an array of `double`.

Comment: @Goz: rarely float is faster than double, unless you are using standard library C functions (because for example `sinf` requires less precision than `sin` it is faster, not because float's are much faster).

Comment: @Robᵩ acc is of type double s and amSeq are of type short.

Comment: @nightcracker:I'm pretty sure you're wrong there.  I've worked on many platform that couldn't actually do double precision without emulation.  Equally in this day and age nearly all floating point code should be going through SIMD units (even when scalar) and without a doubt these ALWAYS run single precision faster than double precision.

Comment: @Goz: perhaps you are right, but the tests I have done (on my computer at least) showed no notable differences.

Comment: @nightcracker: For x87 assembly there will be very little difference (unless you are seriously bandwidth limited) ... but I've not come across another CPU that that is the case for (Or my memory is failing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily avoid the conversions by moving code and using the right types:

```
if(...)
{
    double amSeq = 100;

    for (short c = 0; c <= 21; ++c)
    {
        double s = SeqComp[c];

        for (short kk = (Range.uSequences[k][c]); kk != 0; --kk, --s, --amSeq)
        {
                acc *= s / amSeq;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: After testing the above code and running more tests, i came to realize that the code is slow because multiplication of double precision variables not from the cast_type calls. Integer multiplication is just much faster